# GeoNodes Loop - Extrude Vertex - Delete Point

Tags: geometry-nodes

im trying to make a loop with a simple logic;

**1-** Geonodes creates a line with 5 points *(done)*.

**2-** Points move towards X=3 *(done)*.

**3-** Points reached X=3 will be deleted *(done)*.

**4-** A new point will be spawned on the left side of curve *(this i cant figure).*

**5-** So the total number of point will always be 5.

**Loop :** keeps moving to right , point gets deleted, spawns new one on the opposite side

Need help on 4. , thanks

---

Edit :
Checked [Download .blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/di6iajagnou0f3s/text.blend/file)

[image: Geonodes]

Comment: That's easy, but pls provide blend file, i am too lazy to rebuild all manually. thx.

Comment: Added file , thanks for the help.

Comment: sorry, but your blend file cannot be opened. looks like it is corrupt.

Comment: Sorry for the bad file , no idea why happened , i uploaded again and checked if works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are:

[image]

[image]

i hope you don't mind that i didn't delete, but just moved them ;)

Comment: I need to build on this idea to see if it works , but I had no idea those nodes exist , learned something new non the less :) thanks